# Check string contents using index for Uppercase

Tags: c#

I want to check if a string contains a total of 31 characters and index 0,1,30 are uppercase.  For example:

```
string MyTestString = "INbwzfnpdmcwqq1dl22mcsdeycet2dD";
If (MyTestString.Contains(31 characters and index 0,1,30 are uppercase))
{
// proceed with rest of program
}
```

Comment: And what are the specific problems you're having?

Comment: How does this goes with `linq` so you decided to tag it using this tag?

Comment: Not sure how to go about this.  I tried using .IsUpper but then I would have to create a foreach loop to go through each character.  I would rather use some kind of linq query

Comment: Don't need a `foreach`, you can use the string as an array and stack multiple conditions with `&&`. For the length, just type `MyTestString.` and look at the list of properties for the `string` type, that one is pretty obvious. Seriously, try things yourself. If you're stopped by such simple problems and can't search by yourself, you'll have a **very** hard time later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (str.Length == 31 && new []{ str[0], str[1], str[30] }.All(char.IsUpper))
```

> 31 characters and index 1,2,31 are uppercase

If you have a string with lenght `31` then the last index is 30 because array indices are zero based and therefore starts from `0` to `length - 1`.From [specs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664484%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> For a dimension of length N, indices can range from 0 to N – 1 inclusive

Answer (score 3):

```
if (MyTestString.Length ==31 && Char.IsUpper(MyTestString[0]) && Char.IsUpper(MyTestString[1]) && Char.IsUpper(MyTestString[30]))
{
}
```